# defining a div tag in a td tag in a html table

Tags: html

I am trying to show a map in my website using Openlayers. I use the same code as here:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/all-overlays-google.html

Except, I want to bring it in a table, so that on the left hand side I can put some information about the map! The problem is that if I define the div tag for map in a td tag, when running the map does not show! I pulled it out from td tag and kept it in tr tag and it shows fine! My code is here:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
      <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
      <script src="all-overlays-google.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">
                            Some text here
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 80%;">
                            <div style="width:100%; height:60%" id="map">
                            </div>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add fiddle or add js code for `startApp` to your question.

Comment: `<center>` is *long* deprecated. Stop using it, and *never use it again*. Instead, use CSS.

Comment: @vittore, sorry startApp fuction was for something else and has nothing to do with the problem. I edited the code. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points:

- `<center>` is deprecated. Use CSS `text-align: center`.
- Tables should only be used to display tabular data. Since in your case you don't have tabular data. don't use tables. Instead, use something like

  ```
  <div id="colum-wrapper">
      <div id="left-column">Left</div>
      div id="right-column">Right</div>
  </div>

  #left-column{ float: left; width: /*whatever*/; }
  #right-column{ overflow: hidden; }
  ```

  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GSLb/)
- [Separation of behavior from markup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup): avoid adding event handlers using html attributes if possible.